# Language changing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localization

I have a page where I use language changer. 
This site in Estonian is : http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/ 
and in English is : http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/en/

My problem: If I change language to English, then its working well, but if I go to home page, then its going http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/.

What I want : If page is in Estonia and I click home, then its going to http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/ and if page is in English and I click home, then its going to http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/en/.

How to do this ? Its going always to http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/ because in Menu structure this is Custom page and this URL is http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wordpress/..

Can anybody help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Are you using some WordPress plugin for different languages?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is adding a menu for the English version. So if a visitor is on the English site, you show the English menu, else you show the Estonia menu.

Do you use a plugin for this translation? A plugin like [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) can simplify this proces for you.

Comment: yea its almost works, but the home page and footer menu .... ,how I can set translations for home page and footer menu

Comment: A quick look on the internet shows me that the Stella plugin has a few constants available, including these 2: STELLA_CURRENT_LANG and STELLA_DEFAULT_LANG.

With the first constant you can get the current language, so you can make an if-statement in your code, which selects the Estonia menu when the current language equals to the default language, and selects the English menu when the current language is not the same as the default language.

Comment: I know, but with stella this home button didnt work like its work in polylang. But if I use polylang then the homepage is always in one language. Is there any way to set translation to home page ?

Comment: Are you using Polylang or Stella at the moment? With Polylang, you can create different versions of your pages for every language. Then you can switch to a different language by changing the url or using the language switcher: https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/the-language-switcher/

Comment: Im using polylang atm , and I know it. But how I can set translation to homepage ? Home page is not shown in pages, where I can set translations.

Comment: Is your home page a posts page? Then the translation is in the posts. If your pointing to other translations, then I think they are inside your theme.

Comment: my home page is not a posts page. Yea I think this is inside my theme, but  how I can translate this ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: (Almost) everything is possible :) But you need to be a bit more specific. Your home page isn't a page, nor a posts page, so what is it then? Which theme are you using? Can you show us a bit of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70555/discussion-between-frantsium-and-sjors-roelofs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Polylang plugin, it's easier to manage and edit.
However, I encounter the same problem as you before, where in the second language, when I press the home it goes back to first language's home page.

However it is then solved by a edit in the theme file. You may want to check your theme compatibility with the plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used qtranslate in the past and it's always done it's duty, now there's a new version which I haven't tried yet --> [qtranslate+](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-xp/),

if you got problems with Stella give it a try.